# Fortran LAPACK: high CPU %sys usage with DSYEV - no parallelization - normal?

Tags: linux, fortran, cpu-usage, lapack, blas

*See further update below*

I am observing a quiet high system CPU usage when running my Fortran code. The "user CPU usage" is taking about one core (system is an Intel i7 with 4 cores/ 8 threads, running Linux) whilst system CPU is eating up about 2 cores (hence overall CPU usage about 75%). Can anyone explain to me where this is coming from and if this is "normal" behaviour?

I compile the code with gfortran (optimization turned off -O0, though that part doesn't seem to matter) and link against BLAS, LAPACK and some (other) C-functions. My own code is not using any parallelization and neither does the linked code (as far as I can tell). At least I am not using any parallelized library versions.

The code itself is about assembling and solving finite element systems and uses a lot (?) of allocating and intrinsic function calls (matmul, dot_product), though the overall RAM usage is pretty low (~200MB). I don't know if this information is sufficient/ useful, but I hope someone knows what is going on there.

Best regards,
Ben

**UPDATE**
I think I did track down (part of) the problem to a call to DSYEV from LAPACK (computes eigenvalues of a real symm. matrix A, in my case 3x3).

```
program test

implicit none

integer,parameter :: ndim=3
real(8) :: tens(ndim,ndim)

integer :: mm,nn
real(8), dimension(ndim,ndim):: eigvec
real(8), dimension(ndim)   :: eigval

character, parameter    :: jobz='v'  ! Flags calculation of eigenvectors
character, parameter    :: uplo='u'  ! Flags upper triangular 
integer, parameter      :: lwork=102   ! Length of work array
real(8), dimension(lwork)  :: work      ! Work array
integer :: info   

tens(1,:) = [1.d0, 2.d0, 3.d0]
tens(2,:) = [2.d0, 5.d0, 1.d0]
tens(3,:) = [3.d0, 1.d0, 1.d0]   

do mm=1,5000000    
    eigvec=tens
   ! Call DSYEV
   call dsyev(jobz,uplo,ndim,eigvec,ndim,eigval,work,lwork,info)
enddo

write(*,*) eigvec
write(*,*) int(work(1))

endprogram test
```

The compiling and linking is done with

```
gfortran test.f90 -o test -llapack
```

This program is giving me very high %sys CPU usage. Can anyone verify this (obviously LAPACK is necessary to un the code)? Is this "normal" behaviour or is something wrong with my code/system/librariers...?

**UPDATE 2**
Encouraged by @roygvib's comment I ran the code on another system. On the second system, the high CPU sys usage could not be reproduced. Comparing the two systems I can't seem to find where this is coming from. Both run the same OS version (Linux Ubuntu), same gfortran version (4.8), Kernel Version, LAPACK and BLAS. "Major" difference: the processor is an i7-4770 on the buggy system and an i7-870 on the other. Running the test code on the buggy one is giving me about **%user 16s** and **%sys 28s**. On the i7-870 it is **%user 16s** **%sys 0s**. Running the code four times (parallel) gives me an overall timing for each process of about **18s on the other system** and **44s on the buggy system**. 
Any ideas what else I could look for?

**UPDATE 3**
I think we are getting closer:
Building the test program on the other system with a static link to the LAPACK and BLAS library,

```
gfortran test.f90 -O0 /usr/lib/liblapack.a /usr/lib/libblas.a -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition
```

and running that code in the buggy system gives me a %sys time of about 0 (as desired). On the other hand, building the test program with static links to LAPACK and BLAS on the buggy system and running the code on the other system return high %sys CPU usage as well! So obviously, the libraries seem to differ, right?
Building the static version on the buggy system results in a file size of about 18MB(!), on the other system 100KB. Additionaley I have to include the

```
-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition
```

command only on the other system (otherwise complains about multiple definitions of xerbla), whilst on the buggy system I have to (explicitly) link against libpthread

```
gfortran test.f90 -O0 /usr/lib/liblapack.a /usr/lib/libblas.a -lpthread -o test
```

The interesting thing is that

```
apt-cache policy liblapack*
```

returns the same versions and repo destinations for both systems (same goes for libblas*). Any further ideas? Maybe there is some other command to check library version that I don't know of?

Comment: How many elements does your finite element model have?

Comment: See the comment from the `nmon` developer embedded in this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5738139/620097 . With out a way to reproduce your problem this Q is likely to be considered as off topic (interesting as it may be). Good luck.

Comment: The model I'm currently working on only has about 4000 elements. But the size doesn't seem to be the matter, as I could reprocude the behaviour with even smaller models. The thing is: using commercial FEM code based on Fortran, only a truly single core is used (0% sys CPU usage). So I don't see the point in the comment @shellter hints at.

Comment: Is your LAPACK threaded? Where does your LAPACK and BLAS implementation come from?

Comment: LAPACK and BLAS come from the repo (liblapack3 and libblas3). To my knowledge, those are not threaded, are they?

Comment: Which repo are they from?

Comment: Sorry I missed that detail. It's a university repo, liblapack3 version  3.5.0-2ubuntu1 and libblas3 version 1.2.20110419-7

Comment: I ran your code with Linux (with gfortran4.8 -O0 -llapack), and "time ./a.out" shows 13.34 sec for user time and 0.001 sec for system time, so I cannot reproduce the high system CPU % on my computer...

Comment: Thank you @roygvib for your feedback. I updated the question with further input. May I ask what processor your system is using?

Comment: @PrinceOfMe I'm using Xeon E5-2650 v2 2.60GHz with ScientificLinux 6.7 (x86_64) and gfortran4.8.2. "ldd ./a.out" shows /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3 is used. I also tried "gfortran -O0 /usr/lib/liblapack.dylib" with Core2 Duo 2.5 GHz on MacMini + SnowLeopard (old!), then user time = 21 sec, sys time = 0.023 sec.

Comment: @roygvib I found two more systems that show the same behaviour as the buggy one. It seems to be a problem with the LAPACK and BLAS libraries (see update 3), though I still cannot figure out where it comes from.

Comment: If you have to link against `pthread` it is quite a clear indication that the BLAS library is in fact threaded. When you call it "buggy", is it actually faster or slower? I would expect it to be faster.

Comment: Is it possible that the libraries are actually symlinked to different libraries on the two machines? Commands like "update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3" might be useful (though not sure...) Some pages from google ("ubuntu libblas") [1](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2012/12/19/libblas-and-liblapack-issues-and-speed,-with-scipy-and-ubuntu/) [2](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240932/alternatives-for-shared-libraries-does-that-even-work) And it might be useful to [ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/579786/atlas-lib-symlink-stuck-in-master-slave-deadlock)

Comment: And if multi-thread libraries are used, "top H" etc may be useful to see the situation (e.g. with "OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./a.out &" or with 8).

Comment: @VladimirF I don't know about the `pthread` library, but `ldd` shows it's being linked against on both systems. "Buggy" means more CPU usage but still slower. I think @roygvib found the answer. The `update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3"` points to openblas instead of blas on the "buggy" system. Setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` resolved the issue - only one core is used plus the calculation is faster. Maybe you want to make this an answer and elaborate a bit on OMP_NUM_THREADS and OMP_DYNAMIC. Thanks to all of you!

Comment: That's why I asked **Where does your LAPACK and BLAS implementation come from?** 5 days ago already!!! OpenBLAS should normally be much faster than the reference netlib BLAS.

Comment: @VladimirF, in the end that's true. But I'm by no means an expert when it comes to computer systems and libraries. I am not the sys admin so basically I didn't know openblas is installed. `ldd` did point to the blas (non-parallelized) lib, but I had no idea that this is just a symlink and openblas is set as alternative. Maybe you can elaborate on why openblas seems to choose multiple threads for the test program shown in the Q instead of just running on one core (faster).

Comment: Well it probably tries to speed up some computations by doing it in parallel. However due to some unlucky values of some parameters the parallelization may have too much overhead and be actually slower. Dpends also on your memory bandwith and other factors. TThe reason is probably the fact that your matrices are extremely tiny and actually it could easily be faster to not call LAPACK at all. Parallelization is only good for large enough problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation of the slowdown:

A threaded (probably OpenMP) version of LAPACK and BLAS wes used. These try to launch several threads to solve the linear algebra problem in parallel. That often speeds-up the computation.

However in this case

```
do mm=1,5000000    
   eigvec=tens
   call dsyev(jobz,uplo,ndim,eigvec,ndim,eigval,work,lwork,info)
enddo
```

This is numerous times calling the library for a very small problem (a 3x3 matrix). This cannot be efficiently solved in parallel, the matrix is too small. The overhead connected with the synchronization of the threads dominates the solution time. The synchronization (if not even thread creation) is done **5000000 times**!

Remedies:

1. use a non-threaded BLAS and LAPACK
2. if the parallelization is done using OpenMP set `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` which means *use only one thread*
3. do not use LAPACK at all because for the special case 3x3 there are specialized algorithms available https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#3.C3.973_matrices

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the answer. I do stick to openblas, though I set `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1`. The test program I provided is just a small example and there are more calls to LAPACK/BLAS than just solving the eigenvalues for a 3x3 matrix. Nevertheless, I did change the calls for those small systems from LAPACK to a faster solver. Thanks for the hint!